# Sprite dimension in Generic way not working

Tags: android, android-layout, andengine, game-engine

I have to set a new sprite on background sprite. Background sprite has dimensions set according to dimension of device get through pixel format ..

I am using andengine and ratio Resolution as well but ..

Problem is little bit complex.. I tried to use pixel let say

**Glaxy S3 ha *dimensions 720*1280 And required sprite location is (584,608)**

so i set in manner **( CAMERA_WIDTH/1.233f,CAMERA_HEIGHT/2.112f)**

BUT **HTC experia has dimensions  320*480** So the required positions according to

**( CAMERA_WIDTH/1.233f,CAMERA_HEIGHT/2.112f) is (2599.5,227.27)**

but this wrong according to display... **when i set it on (244,172) for experia its working perfect**.... please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the method :

```
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
this.camara = new Camera(0, 0, camara_width, camera_height);
return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE,
new FillResolutionPolicy(), this.camara).setNeedsSound(true).setNeedsMusic(true);
}
```

the parameter "new FillResolutionPolicy()" auto resize the width and height you only need make for a one resolution and the app run in any smartphone